# How to join a Windows Remote Desktop Connection session?

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, vnc

A remote worker is RDC-ing into a Win7 PC in my LAN and I need to connect occasionally and collaborate with him inside his session, from a Mac.

The hacks that allow multiple RDC clients per session don't work for me when using the OS X RDC client (the first client gets disconnected when a second client tries to connect.)

Tools like join.me are too cumbersome for on-demand instant joining, as they require several steps by the remote worker. Chrome Remote Desktop allows on-demand connection, but it only let's me share into the login screen, not into the active RDC session for some reason. I haven't experimented yet with VNC.

Is there some way for me to be able to instantly connect into the running RDC session, based only on some one-time configuration on the PC?

Comment: Its my understand that Desktop versions of Windows didn't even support multiple sessions.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm not referring to multiple sessions (which would allow independent usage and effectively violate the single-license of the desktop version), but to multiple users connected to the same session -- much in the way that VNC normally allows.

Answer (score 3):

It's quite easy. Get your user to log into an RDP session.  Then log into the same server using your credentials.  Go to Remote Desktop Services Manager. Then right click on the Active user whose session you want to join and click Remote Control. They will receive a permission message and that's it - you're in the same session.

Answer (score 0):

You could use LogMeIn, that allows you to connect via a web page, and see their screen just as they do.  I use it for remote assistance for my family.
The other option is that if you can RDP into the computer as well, you can go into Task Manager -> Users -> Right-click their name -> Remote Control.
That will send them a request to allow you to remote control their session, and as soon as they accept it, you can see and interact with their screen just like they do.  Only thing to bear in mind with that is the default key to stop controlling is the asterisk(*) on the NUMPAD, not the on on the keyboard proper.